# How to bind to UIElement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to pass the parent `Window` in to a command so that it can be used for a `RoutedCommand`. Is there any way to do this with `Dependency Properties`? Ive seen a lot of questions that say this isn't possible because it isn't part of the visual tree, but the below works:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Main}" .../>
```

The parameter is actually set as `Main` (the parent Window). So, how can I do this on my custom object with a `Dependency Property`?

The error I get when I try to set it on my own object DP:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'CommandGroup' (HashCode=25702951); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

My class is as follows:

```
public class CommandGroup : DependencyObject, ICommand
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof (object), typeof (CommandGroup));

  public object CommandParameter
  {
    get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
  }

  ....
}
```

I want to set the XAML as below:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Command>
    <CommandGroup CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=Main}>
    ...
```

Comment: What didn't work when you used that on your DP? It should have just worked, assuming it worked on the command parameter.

Comment: The dependency property would have to be added to your custom Button.  Did You want pass values to CommandParameter via binding instead?

Comment: @user2880486 I added my class, which shows I did add the DP. The problem has to do with the binding source as near as I can tell...

Comment: I mean your class would have to be inherited from Button.  Something like MyClass : Button. DP appears on the left side of = so you'd have <MyClass MyDP="{Binding...}"  If you are thinking of <Button CommandParameters="{Binding MyDP"}, it won't work.  There are a few ways to pass parameters via binding to a button.  Are you using MVVM?  You might want to post the code for your class as well.

Comment: @user2880486 I think you are misunderstanding the problem. I just added what the XAML should look like

Comment: That sure *seems* like it should work. I'm not sure. Of course, I normally don't bind against controls, so that might have something to do with it... Did you try adding Path=. to it?

Comment: I do not think it works because you are setting button.command to commandgroup then binding the commandgroup's dependency property to some value.  The commandgroup is not part of the visual tree in this case.

Comment: Why would you do this at all? If you set the Button's CommandParameter (as in your first XAML snippet), that value would be passed to the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods of your CommandGroup. So there seems to be no need for an additional CommandParameter property.

Comment: @Clemens That is what I'm doing, however it is a really crappy use. Realistically, I wanted to name it `RoutedCommandTarget` or something so that it was at least a little more obvious what its purpose is. Hijacking another property is cheap, dirty, and bad for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Because CommandParameter is not a visual or logical tree element, it cannot inherit DataContext.

...but when your object is `Freezable`, it can inherit DataContext.

```cs
public class CommandGroup : Freezable, ICommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof (object), typeof (CommandGroup));

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new CommandGroup();
    }
}
```

See:
https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/